How to post data from a form back to database via a Razor page
In my asp.net core client, I have a view Razor page (index.cshtml) that displays data.  When scaffolding the class links were generated (Edit, Delete, )
I am now trying to wire the “Edit” link
When Edit link is clicked, The Edit Action (not entire code shown)
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int id) 
StudentModel courses = new StudentModel();

is fired and form with only 5 fields is populated:
  StudentId=26
  Courses = math
  fName = Peter
  lName =Smith
  Grade = B

so this part works. Now work on the submit button.  I am trying to save back (e.g. Grade) to database.
For the submit button, created this Action
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(StudentModel mosdel)
{
    try
    {
            
           
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mosdel);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PutAsync(_client.BaseAddress + "/Students/Update/", content).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

            

}
catch (Exception)
{

    return View();
}

return View();

}
When click on submit button and debug, it shows this line fails with 404 Not Found
HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PutAsync(_client.BaseAddress + "/Students/Update/", content).Result;

So
return RedirectToAction("Index");
never gets executed
I verified the End-point using the Swagger UI by
entering the required  “id” then I can update any of the related body parameters
{
  "courses": "string",
  "fName": "string",
  "lName": "string",
  "Grade": "string"
}

I can also test the end-point using postman by using a PUT request and adding the id (e.g. 26)
https://localhost:7385/api/Students/Update/26
and then the body
{
  "courses": "string",
  "fName": "string",
  "lName": "string",

  "Grade": "C"
}

I tried to remove all fields, so the form (razor page) has only one field (“Grade”)  and the “submit” button…no luck
Any ideas what else I can try?

Do you have 2 different projects in your solution? If so, have you tried to create a simple Get endpoint and try whether you got 404 or not? Just like you know, 404 means didn't find the endpoint. By the way, does the base address you defined is https://localhost:7385/api?

I had a test with code below which work well.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> testputAsync() {
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    StudentModel mod = new StudentModel {
        StudentId = 26,
        Courses="math",
        fName="Peter",
        lName="Smith",
        Grade="b"
    };
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mod);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PutAsync("https://localhost:7064/Students/Update/", content).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
}

[Route("Students/Update")]
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult updateGame([FromBody] StudentModel update)
{
    return Ok();
}


But according to your description, you had a test with postman, which url is https://localhost:7385/api/Students/Update/26 and it worked. So that I'm afraid the Put request should be something similar to codes below.
[Route("Students/Update/{studentId:int}")]
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult updateGame(int studentId, [FromBody] StudentModel update)
{
    return Ok();
}

If so, our request should be changed to HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PutAsync("https://localhost:7064/Students/Update/26", content).Result; otherwise we will get 404 error.

by the way, we'd better to use await instead of  .Result
